# IQueryable and custom filtering - use Expression<Func<>>?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, filtering

I face a problem, which is new to me

I have the following entity (I use the fluent nhibernate but it doesn't matter here)

```
public class SomeEntity
{
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

filter classes:

```
public class FilterOptions
{
    public string logic { get; set; }             // "and", "or"
    public FilterItems[] filters { get; set; }
}

public class FilterItems
{
    public string @operator { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }           //string value provided by user
}
```

the `@operator` property can have the following values

```
EndsWith
DoesNotContain
Contains
StartsWith
NotEqual
IsEqualTo
```

all I wanna do is to do some filter operations basing on the 2 filters:

```
private IQueryable<SomeEntity> BuildQuery(FilterOptions opts)
{
    IQueryable<SomeEntity> query = Session.Query<SomeEntity>();

    var firstFilter = opts.filters[0];
    var secondFilter = opts.filters[1];
}
```

because the fact the `@operator` property can have so many options, I wonder if there's a posibility to have the external method with the `swich` operator, and use that method inside of the `.Where` method.

Something like

```
  var query = query.Where(firstSwitchFilterMethod && secondFilterMethod)
```

pseudo code:

```
firstSwitchFilterMethod:

if (firstFilter.@operator == "Contains")
    return SomeEntity.Name.Contains(firstFilter.value);
```

and so on...

Any ideas ? I'm thinking about the `Expression<Func<>>` - is it good direction ? If so, how to use it in my case ?

Or, maybe build my own the extension method for `SomeEntity` which will be using that filter class ?

Answer (score 2):

You can not make arbitrary function call expression and expect that it can be translated into SQL. But there are some functions, like StartsWith, that can. Here is one example, how You can build Your own expression:

```
protected IQueryable<T> GetFiltered<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string filterOnProperty, string startsWithString, string endsWithString)
{
    LambdaExpression startsWithLambda = (Expression<Func<string, string, bool>>)((x, s) => x.StartsWith(s));
    MethodInfo startsWithMI = (startsWithLambda.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;

    LambdaExpression endsWithLambda = (Expression<Func<string, string, bool>>)((x, s) => x.EndsWith(s));
    MethodInfo endsWithMI = (endsWithLambda.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;

    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression nameProp = Expression.Property(param, filterOnProperty);

    Expression filteredOk = Expression.Constant(true);

    Expression startsWithStringExpr = Expression.Constant(startsWithString);
    Expression startsWithCondition = Expression.Call(nameProp, startsWithMI, startsWithStringExpr);
    filteredOk = Expression.AndAlso(filteredOk, startsWithCondition);

    Expression endsWithStringExpr = Expression.Constant(endsWithString);
    Expression endsWithCondition = Expression.Call(nameProp, endsWithMI, endsWithStringExpr);
    filteredOk = Expression.AndAlso(filteredOk, endsWithCondition);

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> where = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filteredOk, new ParameterExpression[] { param });

    return query.Where(where);
}
```

usage is simple

```
DCDataContext dc = new DCDataContext();
var query = dc.testtables.AsQueryable();

query = GetFiltered(query, "name", "aaa", "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate or any other LINQ provider doesn't really care how you build the expression - the only thing that matters is that the final expression only contain constructs that the LINQ provider understands and knows what to do with.

Yes, you can have a method return an `Expression<Func<>>` and then add that expression to the LINQ query using the `Where()` method.

However, you cannot ask NHibernate to analyze your compiled code and convert the if statement to SQL. You method will need to analyze the options and return a suitable expression that gets inserted into the full LINQ query.

You can write it in a single method like this:

```
IQueryable<SomeEntity> query = Session.Query<SomeEntity>();

if (isEqOp)
    query = query.Where(e => e.Name == options.Value)

if (isContainsOp)
    query = query.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(options.Value))

query.ToList();
```

Or if you want the filter logic in a separate method as you said you can also split it like this:

```
public Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> GetExpression(options)
{
    if (isEqOp)
        return (Entity e) => e.Name == options.Value;

    if (isContainsOp)
        return (Entity e) => e.Name.Contains(options.Value);
}


{
     IQueryable<SomeEntity> query = Session.Query<SomeEntity>();
     query = query.Where(GetExpression(options))
     ...
}
```